# Reorderable List View not working when used in Drawer

Tags: flutter, drawer, reorderable-list

I need to use a reorderable list in a drawer. For that, I create a widget. When I use the widget in the main screen/scaffold/build: everything is ok.

But when I use the very same widget in a drawer I get an app exception, suggesting to fill in a bug report.

Do I need to do something else when using the widget in a drawer or is this really a bug?

A simplified version of my program:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _myDrawer(),
      drawer: Container(child: _myDrawer()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class _myDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  _myDrawer({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __myDrawerState createState() => __myDrawerState();
}

class __myDrawerState extends State<_myDrawer> {
  List<String> _sortList = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Date'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ReorderableListView(onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
          //scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          //padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[0]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[0]),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[1]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[1]),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[2]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[2]),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

The crash report is this:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart':
Failed assertion: line 111 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      ScrollController.position (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:111:12)
#3      ScrollController.offset (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart:118:24)
#4      _ReorderableListContentState._scrollTo (package:flutter/src/material/reorderable_list.dart:322:51)
#5      _ReorderableListContentState._wrap.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/reorderable_list.dart:543:11)
#6      _DragTargetState.didEnter (package:flutter/src/widgets/drag_target.dart:522:88)
...
Handler: "onStart"
Recognizer: DelayedMultiDragGestureRecognizer#1c0a1
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue you mentioned. I see the drawer properly when I tap on it:

[image]

Here's the complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      //   body: _myDrawer(),
      drawer: Container(child: _MyDrawer())
    );
  }
}

class _MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyDrawer({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __MyDrawerState createState() => __MyDrawerState();
}

class __MyDrawerState extends State<_MyDrawer> {
  List<String> _sortList = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Date'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ReorderableListView(onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {},
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[0]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[0]),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[1]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[1]),
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              key: ValueKey(_sortList[2]),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(_sortList[2]),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I am latest stable Flutter version.